# Openrowset connection issue with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

Over the years, I've used `OPENROWSET` queries on one instance to access data on another SQL Server instance. As long as ad-hoc queries were enabled, this worked fine regardless of the SQL Server instance versions.

We just installed two new SQL Server 2014 instances and I can use `OPENROWSET` between those 2014 instances or from a 2014 instance I can access data on a lower version instance. However, I get the error below when I try run an `OPENROWSET` query from a 2012 or lower instance to get data from a 2014 instance.

Thanks

***Error *****

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>
> Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

Comment: I can tell you that you should have no issue being able to use `OPENROWSET` from 2012 to your 2014 server. I am doing this from 2008 server to a 2014 server and it works with no issues. It sounds more like your 2014 isn't allowing outside connections because of a firewall rule or possibly configuration related. That's where I would start.

Comment: My mistake, it does work from another 2012 instance.  Just not a 2008, 2008 R2 or 2005 instance.